# How to add SNMP masks through an MIB Browser?

Tags: snmp, mib

Do all MIB browsers have a provision to add SNMP masks? Specifically, does the ManageEngine MIB Browser Free Tool allow for adding SNMP masks?

Answer (score 0):

If you were referring to the family mask, part of SNMP VACM, then you should check the specification of the MIB Browser you are using.

As long as the product claims to fully support [RFC 3415](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3415#section-2.4.2), then it should support family mask feature.

But this really depends on the vendors.